Tests passing in IntelliJ, failing using mvn
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;


import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;


@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CheckStatusTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private CheckStatus checkStatus;

    @Test
    public void testIsSupported() {
        boolean isSupported;
        for (Status status : Status.values()) {
            isSupported = checkStatus.isSupported(status, false);
            if (Status.STATUS_DELIVERED.equals(status)) {
                assertTrue(isSupported);
            } else {
                assertFalse(isSupported);
            }
        }
    }
}

In here the tests are passing in IntelliJ test runner but failing when running
mvn test or mvn clean install
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

The test is for a simple method which returns true if status is delivered.
The test is passing when using IntelliJ runner and failing when running mvn test or mvn clean install.
mvn version - 3.9.6 (plugin of IntelliJ)
jdk - corretto-1.8.0_412 (Installed using IntelliJ)

Please provide minimum check status class, and what error you are getting

please provide full pom.xml file and the error what you are getting,.

Please [edit] your question and make it a [mcve].
